# How to make 4x1 size widget on Android homescreen?

Tags: android, widget, homescreen

I have difficulties developing 4x1 widget for Android.

This is the appprovider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/main" />
```

And here is the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"> 
//content goes here
</LinearLayout>
```

I could see the widget but the size is 4x2. I confuse why I cannot have 4x1 widget size?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the height of the LinearLayout to a smaller value *(or even better, to `fill_parent`)*? The dimension is bigger than your "worst case cell size" of 72dp, so maybe the launcher says internally "this doesn't fit into one cell, let's use two instead".

Comment: Yes, I tried fill_parent. Still the widget remain 4x2...

Comment: After Cleaning and rebuild the project. It works now :)
Newbie mistakes...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I don't think it's a newbie mistake.. I've had an appWidget that was 1x1 cell in size. I set it to 72dp x 72dp, and it was working fine.. But it seems like Google changed the widget dimension sizing formula from

```
(cells * 74) - 2
```

to

```
(cells * 70) - 30
```

So now the default size of my widget has to be 40dp x 40dp..

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy_determining_size

Answer (score 4):

In ICS it must be showing 4x2.

To correct this make a folder in 'res' name 'xml-v14':

Define your widget appwidget-provider with same xml name here. just change minHeight to 40dp.
This will correct the error.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the problem is here:

> **android:layout_height="100dp"**

If you fix it (layout_height) in this size (100dp) you can not change the Widget size less than it as you set 75dp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"> 
    //content goes here
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Generally better to describe what you changed in the text of your answer. Marking up the code with comments and leaving the text vague makes it hard to follow.

Comment: I did it , Thank you