# Android 4x1 widget size

Tags: android, widget

I am developing an application that supports widget sizes 4x1, 4x2 and 5x2. Everything works well except that the 4x1 widget takes the size of a 4x2widget. I have checked the widget provide file and it seems ok:

The layout also is ok (I Have tried changing its width and height to fill_parent as some other people suggested) but whatever I did, when I put it on the home screen, it has a 4x1 size but it is centered vertically on a 4x2 size on the screen. It is like the size of the layout is correct (I have added a background color to see how high it is) but something is forcing the widget to size 4x2.

Anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: What are the minWidth and minHeight values set to in your AppWidgetProvider XML info definition?

Comment: The minWidth is 294dp and the minHeight is 72dp. I have tested it on a Samsung GS3 with ICS and it works ok. On a Samsung GS2 it does not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make 4x1 size widget on Android homescreen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101955/how-to-make-4x1-size-widget-on-android-homescreen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the minHeight value to 40dp solved the problem.

Comment: yes the formula for height has changed according to answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11289215/383414

Answer (score 4):

The minWidth and minHeight have to be 72 dp per 1x1 block for widgets. You most likeley have something else than 72 dp, and everything inbeetween 144 and 73 dp makes it use 2 blocks in instead of 1.

Comment: The minWidth is 294dp and the minHeight is 72dp. I have tested it on a Samsung GS3 with ICS and it works ok. On a Samsung GS2 it does not.

Comment: When I made a widget I used 70 dp instead(I got a crappy small phone) and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

May be a late reply but Google seems to have changed the formula for Widget Dimension to (n * 70) - 30.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy_determining_size